# C++ trying to calculate total from input file

Tags: c++

My project is to read an input file with a set of integers (I do not know how many), calculate the total of those integers, then create an output file and write the total on the output file.

**Everything in my code works except the total I get from the output file is not actually the total that I'm trying to calculate.**

For example, the integers contained on my testfile1 document are: 14, 9, 12, -6, -30, 8, 109

The number I'm getting on my sum document reads 28, which is clearly not the total of these integers.

Here is my code.  I know some parts are redundant or not as simple as c++ could be, but I tried to format it according to what I have learned so far from my textbook, so some of it might not be as advanced.  Certain line numbers are missing because I took out the description blocks.
**I really just need to figure out why the total is not adding correctly (lines 33-38)**.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Thank you all so much in advanced!**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {

   ifstream inputFile;
   ofstream outputFile;
   string testfile1;
   string sum;
   int total=0;
   int num;

   cout << "Please input name of file." << endl;
   getline (cin, testfile1);

   inputFile.open(testfile1.c_str());

   if(inputFile) {
      while(inputFile >> num){
         total=+num;
      }
      inputFile.close();
   }
   else {
      cout << "could not access testfile1" << endl;
   }
   outputFile.open("sum");

   if(outputFile) {
      outputFile << total << endl;
      outputFile.close();
   }
   else {
      cout << "could not access file." << endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried writing the numbers read as you go?

Comment: It's surprising you get 28, and not 109.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  After trying that, I am still getting the wrong total.

Comment: @Jamie_QQ Posting code with line numbers isn't that helpful towards a [MCVE].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typo.

Use

```
total += num;  // Need to use +=
```

instead of

```
total=+num;  // Not =+.
```

Comment: That fixed it.  Thank you so much!